# setup atomsite on iis7?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7

I downloaded atomsite , opened  it in visual studio, published  it to somewhere c:\blog file systems then copied it to  (c:\intepub\wwwroot\blog),

then in IIs7, right click on blog , convert to application

all done,
but when i browse http://localhost/blog, it shows a blank screen....

what do i need more to start blogging??
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to `localhost/blog/Wizard/TestInstall`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried  http://localhost:8080/blog ? Or from the IIS right click on the site and then preview or so.. it's been ages since I used IIS =[.